Unable to Read QR Code (Model I) in Expo Camera (Next)
I have been using expo-camera to read QR codes (Model II, most common qr codes) in my app. This is working correctly but now I have some QR Codes that are the older Model I, the camera view is unable to read these.
In the documentation: there is only qrcode type. There is no option to specify a specific subtype.
I want to ask if it is possible to read these QR Codes using Expo Camera, or through any other alternative.
Here is an example of a QR code that I am talking about:


You should try with a higher quality image as it looks a bit fuzzy to me. From what I've been able to figure out expo-camera is using Google's MLKit to decode the barcodes. Don't know if expo-camera surfaces parts of the MLKit API mentioned in L Kit Barcode Scanning doesn't detect QR codes in the photo of the monitor screen

I had to take a photo to share here, but in actuality, it is printed so it isn't an issue of distortion, lighting or low-quality image.
